# Run pigpiod daemon - Using python or Ubuntu boot

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

In order to use pigpio Module in Python (remote GPIO for Raspberry Pi ), `pigpiod` has to be loaded to memory on each RPi.

1. what is the right way to to it ? during Ubuntu's boot or a part of Python's script ?
2. since It needs `sudo pigpiod`- how is it done (both Ubuntu and Python )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in [gpiozero documentation](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative it to use the reboot option within cron

Run:

```
crontab -e
```

then add the entry:

```
@reboot    /pathtoexecutable
```

This will run the process every time the system boots.

Comment: Daemon is not loaded after boot. How can I debug?

Comment: I think it needs to be run as sudo - maybe the system cron will do this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `pigpiod`, but I'm assuming it's a daemon (a long running Linux process) that you want to start at boot. The standard way to do that in most modern Linux systems (including Raspberri Pi, I think) is to use `systemd`. Give the following commands a try:

```
systemctcl start pigpiod # start it now
systemctl enable pigpiod # start it each boot
systemctl status pigpiod # make sure it started
# https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs
journalctl -u pigpiod # Use this to see logs.
```

If `systemctl` complains about not being able to find the service, you'll have to create a service file for it. This is a text file you place in a directory that tells systemd how to deamonize the process. [Here](http://neilwebber.com/notes/2016/02/10/making-a-simple-systemd-file-for-raspberry-pi-jessie/) is a blog post where someone does this, and Google should find you others if it doesn't help.

Then you should be able to connect with Python.

Comment: firstly- thanks! second - won't systemctl ask for `sudo` password during boot ( or won't load it due to lack of ) ?

Comment: @Guy.D `systemctl` is a frontend for `systemctl`, which already runs as root, so it doesn't need to ask for it.

Comment: guy@rpi2:~$ systemctl start pigpiod
Failed to start pigpiod.service: Unit pigpiod.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status pigpiod.service' for details.
guy@rpi2:~$ systemctl enable pigpiod
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pigpiod.service to /lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service.

Comment: guy@rpi2:~$ systemctl status pigpiod.service
\u25cf pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/pigpiod.service.d
           \u2514\u2500public.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: @Guy.D sorry, man, without more knowledge of `pigpiod` and probably looking at at what the service file is doing, I can't really help. You'll have to look through the logs and debug it. Or, you could use @RamanSailopal's solution and see if that works. `systemctl disable pigpiod` should remove the symlink. Good luck!